# sql code for sets

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I use a function `f(x,y)` in sql to calculate this series:

```
f(x,y)=x-y^3/3!+x^5/5!-y^7/7!+....
```

I wrote factorial function and used while loop and count till parameter<=32 and with `convert(varchar(50),@answer)`

It can calculate without stackoverflow error but how can I use this function (or proc) in this set?

How can we simulate this set without using factorial function?

For example

```
x^5/5!
```

is simulate with

```
x^3/3!*x^2/5*4   .....
```

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Welcome - please show us the code you've tried, it helps us to have something to work off of and know your problem a little better

Comment: thanks    this is the factorialprocedure    create proc factorial @x int,@answer bigint   as begin declare @c int> if (@x<0 or @x>33>)begin return -1 end> select @c=1,@answer=1

while (@c<@x and @x<>0) begin set @answer=@answer*(@c+1) set @c=@c+1 end return end declare @answer bigint,@x int select @x=0 while (@x<=33) begin exec factorial @x,@answer select convert(varchar(50),@x)+'!'+convert(varchar(50),@x) select @x=@x+1 end but i think it's only a small part of the code this set needs....

Comment: This isn't too hard, unless you care about performance.  If you do, then you should either look at SQLCLR or calculating it on the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you need this specific infinite series only, it converges to this combination of sin() and sinh() values for all x. (Check my math to be sure, using the Taylor series for sin and sinh.)

```
f(x,y) = (sin(x)-sinh(-x))/2 + (sin(y)+sinh(-y))/2
```

This expresses the result you want without a loop, but unfortunately, the hyperbolic sine function sinh() is not available in T-SQL. You could make the .NET math.sinh function available to SQL Server by creating a CLR user-defined function for it. (You could also make the entire function f(x,y) a CLR function.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the series of factors (shown as 3,5,7) increase as the set of odd numbers. In this solution, I'm using common-table expressions which means you must be using SQL Server 2005 or later.

```
Declare @x float;
Declare @y float;

-- this is the first factor evaluated
-- e.g., in the example, 3 is the first factor
-- values less that one effectively set the min
-- to one.
Declare @FactorMin int;

-- this is the maximum number of iterations
-- i.e., 3, 5, 7, 
Declare @FactorMax int

Set @x = 20;
Set @y = 20;
Set @FactorMin = 3;
Set @FactorMax = 15;

With Numbers As
    (
    Select 1 As Value
    Union All
    Select Value + 1
    From Numbers
    Where Value < @FactorMax
    )
    , OddNumbers As
    (
    Select Value
        , Row_Number() Over( Order By Value ) As Position
    From Numbers
    Where Value % 2 = 1
        And Value Between @FactorMin And @FactorMax
    )
    , Factorials As
    (
    Select O.Value, O.Position
        , Exp(Sum(Log(N1.Value))) As Factorial
        , Case When O.Position % 2 = 1 Then -1 * @y Else @x End As XOrY
    From OddNumbers As O
        Cross Join Numbers As N1
    Where N1.Value <= O.Value
    Group By O.Value, O.Position
    )
Select Sum( Z.Value )
From    (
        Select @x As Value
        Union All   
        Select Power(XOrY, Value) / Factorial
        From Factorials 
        ) As Z  
Option (MaxRecursion 0);
```